# Should I allow IP 0.0.0.0 in iptables?

Tags: networking, iptables

I just created new VPS and setup iptables, and I see this in logs:

```
 IN=eth0 OUT= MAC=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:00:50:56:94:c9:82:08:00 SRC=0.0.0.0 DST=255.255.255.255 LEN=328 TOS=0x00 PREC=0x00 TTL=16 ID=0 PROTO=UDP SPT=68 DPT=67 LEN=308
```

I really wonder what that source 0.0.0.0 and destination 255.255.255.255 mean. It sends packet like every 2 seconds.

I know that IP 0.0.0.0 is like loopback (127.0.0.1), but is accessible for anyone outside. So I really wonder what it could be, it is new VPS with Debian 9 without any server running on it.

So I don't know if I should allow it (for security reasons) and what is the best rule to allow it, isn't there any kind of rule which allow all these kinds of loopback addresses?

Comment: Did you truncate part of that log?  What was the SPT/DPT values?  Is there DHCP on that network?

Comment: @Zoredache I updated topic with whole log.

Comment: `PROTO=UDP SPT=68 DPT=67` that is DHCP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very likely DHCP REQUEST. As it is coming IN you can likely ignore it as long as the VPS you are creating is not going to be DHCP server.

Comment: I updated topic with whole log. so it is only DHCP right?